# Problem to add new User Spring-Boot / Postman

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, postman

Can you help me? I have a problem adding a new client to my database.

I have three classes: User, Role, Center

my user class contains:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String login;
private String password;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String telephone;
private String email;
private long idCCMS;
private String matricule;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Code_Role")
private Role role;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Code_Centre")
private Centre centre;
```

my method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public Utilisateur save(@RequestBody Utilisateur user) {
    return userRepo.save(user);
}
```

How I can affect the addition of a new user by assigning him a role and a center.
I tried this solution with postman :

```
{
    "login": "med",
    "password": "123456789",
    "nom": "AOUIDIDI",
    "prenom": "MOHAMED WALID",
    "telephone": "(+222) 22-222-222",
    "email": "aaa@aaa.com",
    "idccms": 08318915,
    "matricule": "431908",
    "code_role":"3",
    "code_centre":"3"
}
```

I got this result:

```
"timestamp": "2020-02-06T13:15:41.496+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 16]",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 16]\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:245)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 16]\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase.reportInvalidNumber(ParserMinimalBase.java:551)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._verifyNoLeadingZeroes(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1519)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parsePosNumber(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1371)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1055)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:376)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3258)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239)\r\n\t... 51 more\r\n",
    "path": "/utilisateurs/add"
}
```

can you help me solve this problem please ?

Comment: `"idccms": 08318915` ..can you make the request "without trailing zero"?

Comment: The stack trace error is quite clear. One of your values is `08318915` and is not a valid number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your response says:

> ...line: 8, column: 16 ...  Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed

`"idccms": 08318915` can not be parsed to `private long idCCMS;`

Either get rid of the `0` in the beginning or make `idCCMS` a type of `String` and everything will be just fine.

Comment: I changed the type of "idccms" from Long to String, but when adding a new user it puts it in an empty field in the database

Comment: This is the result of my Request : {
    "id": 1,
    "login": "med",
    "password": "123456789",
    "nom": "AOUIDIDI",
    "prenom": "MOHAMED WALID",
    "telephone": "(+222) 22-222-222",
    "email": "aaa@aaa.com",
    "idCCMS": null,
    "matricule": "431908",
    "role": null,
    "centre": null
}

Comment: I don't know how exactly do you save data in your DB, so I can't answer why your database field is not being filled. Name of the field in `@Entity` should correspond with the name of the column in the database. Try putting `@Column(name = "exact_column_name_in_db")` on the field `private String idCCMS;`